# plc not reading photo eye

Tags: plc

I recently changed a photo eye and it's all wired and on functioning property but when it comes to the plc it's not changing the status on the input card? What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you changed it from a PNP type to an NPN type or vice versa it might appear to be working, light changing and all, but the PLC would not be able to read it. For example, from a Micro Detectors datasheet:

[image]

PLCs that use a contact closure to 0V would require the NPN type.

Answer (score 0):

Bad Input card? With this little information it is exceptionally hard to troubleshoot remotely.

Check for Voltage at the PLC Input card, make sure you don't have a loose / broken wire.

Wire + Control Voltage to the input pin, see if it comes on.

That should help narrow down the search.